# How many mice can I keep in this cage?

Tags: mice

I  have been doing research into keeping mice and I know that there are numerous calculators out there but they do not take into account the different levels and thought I would ask the experts about this cage

I have been given it and would love to be able to use it and was wondering how many mice you guys would recommend keeping in it
https://www.petsathome.com/shop/en/pets/rosewood-pico-hamster-home-extra-large-teal
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this one? http://www.cagecalc.de/simple.py?lang=eng&conf=mice

It includes levels. I'm not a mice keeper so I couldn't tell you without using the calculator.